# How do I assign a score to a specific number in java array list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am new to java and have to assign a monetary win to the number 2 of a dice roll simulation. I am rolling 6 dice and for every 2 which appears in the play I want to be able to assign a higher prize, e.g. rolling 1 number 2 out of 6 dice would win £1, rolling 2 number 2's would win £5, rolling 3 number 2's would win £15.

My dice class code is as follows:

```java
public void diceRoll() {
    Random rnd = new Random(); // Random number generator
    String resultRoll;

    // sets dice numbers 1 to 6
    int n1 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1); // roll will return a number from 1 to 7
    int n2 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
    int n3 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
    int n4 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
    int n5 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);
    int n6 = 1 + rnd.nextInt(7-1);

    resultRoll = n1 + "\n" 
                + n2 + "\n" 
                + n3 + "\n" 
                + n4 + "\n" 
                + n5 + "\n" 
                + n6; // result of the roll will list the results from all 6 individual dice
                            
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You rolled: " + resultRoll); // dialog box presenting list of dice results
                
    Integer[] rolls = new Integer[] {n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6};
    List<Integer> rollsList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(rolls)); //This creates an array list so we can 
                
    rollsList.contains(2);
    System.out.print(rollsList.contains(2));
}

public int playerTurn (int playerTurn) {
    int playerTakesTurn = playerTurn + 1;
    return playerTakesTurn;
}
```

Comment: You can have a `Map<Integer,Integer>` where the number -> prize is mapped. And you can then lookup the rollsList values against this Map to find the prize.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could also utilize a 2D int Array if you wanted, for example:

```
// A Score Table to establish the amount given for
// the number of 2's that come up in a six dice roll.
int[][] scoreTable = {
    {1, 1},
    {2, 5},
    {3, 15},
    {4, 30},
    {5, 60},
    {6, 100}
};
Random rnd = new Random(); // Random number generator
Integer[] rolls = new Integer[6];
final String LS = System.lineSeparator();
String resultRoll = "";
int score;
int playTotal = 0;
int rollCounter = 0;
boolean playAgain = true;

while (playAgain) {
    rollCounter++;
    // sets dice numbers 1 to 6
    int twoCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        rolls[i] = rnd.nextInt(6) + 1; // roll will return a number from 1 to 6
        if (rolls[i] == 2) {
            twoCounter++;
            score = scoreTable[twoCounter - 1][1];
        }
    }

    // result of the roll will list the results from all 6 individual dice
    playTotal += score;
    resultRoll = new StringBuilder("<html>You Rolled:<br><br><center>Dice 1 & 2:&emsp;&emsp;")
            .append(rolls[0]).append(",&emsp;").append(rolls[1])
            .append("</center><br><center>Dice 3 & 4:&emsp;&emsp;")
            .append(rolls[2]).append(",&emsp;").append(rolls[3])
            .append("</center><br><center>Dice 5 & 6:&emsp;&emsp;")
            .append(rolls[4]).append(",&emsp;").append(rolls[5])
            .append("</center><br><br>Your Score this roll:&emsp;<font color=blue>£")
            .append(score).append("</font><br>")
            .append("Total Won so far:&emsp;&emsp; <font color=red><b>£")
            .append(playTotal).append("</b></font><br></html>").toString();
        
    // Display results of roll...
    String[] buttonCaptions = {"Roll Again", "Quit"};
    int res = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, resultRoll, "Six Dice Roll #" 
                + rollCounter, 0, -1, null, buttonCaptions, buttonCaptions[0]);
    // Is first button (Roll Again) selected?
    if (res != 0) {
        // No... it's not so quit!
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for playing. Bye-Bye.");
        playAgain = false;
    }
}
```